# Syntax Directed Definition for differentiation of expressions

Tags: syntax, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I've been reading Syntax Directed Definitions from ALSU- Compilers textbook and came across this exercise question. Actually this question asks us to write the productions also with corresponding Semantic rules.

[Question from Alfred V. Aho, Monica S. Lam, Ravi Sethi, Jeffrey, Ullman- Compilers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af6E0.png)

I'm pretty sure the productions for the given grammar would be -

1. E --> E + E
2. E --> E * E
3. E --> T
4. T --> id (which is x in this case)
5. T --> num

Are these productions correct? (If not plz help with that too)
Can anyone help me in figuring out what could be the semantic actions for corresponding productions
so translated output would differentiated value of input expression?

Comment: Productions look good to me. Writing semantic actions require knowledge about what you're generating code for - an abstract stack machine, perhaps?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError well yeah that seems fine to consider